# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.earworm.backendearworm.UserService required a bean of type

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, spring-repositories

Me and my team are having trouble getting our spring boot application to run and we try to fix one thing that then leads to another error. I have been looking around but cant seem to find the answer. this is the link to our github of our project. https://github.com/matfitchell/Earworm/tree/main/SourceCode/BackEnd/src/main/java/com/earworm

error when trying to run spring boot:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.earworm.backendearworm. UserService required a bean of type com.earworm.backendearworm.UserRepository that could not be found

I have tried adding different dependencies to our project.
UserService.java

```html
package com.earworm.backendearworm;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.earworm.registration.token.ConfirmationToken;
import com.earworm.registration.token.ConfirmationTokenService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
            ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.confirmationTokenService = confirmationTokenService;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }




    public String addNewUser(User user) {
        Optional<User> userByEmail = userRepository.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (userByEmail.isPresent()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email taken");
        }
        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        userRepository.save(user);

        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(token, LocalDateTime.now(),
                LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15), user);

        confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);

        return token;
    }
    */
    /*
     * Fix exists by ID by actually passing id and changing repository from string
     * to long
     */
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        boolean userExists = userRepository.existsById(id);
        if (!userExists) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("User with id " + id + " does not exist");
        }
        userRepository.deleteById(id);

    }

    // Name and email are optional
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(Long id, String username, int zipCode, String bio) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("User with id " + id + " does not exist"));

        if (username != null && username.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(user.getUsername(), username)) {
            user.setUsername(username);
        }
        // -------Change email if wanted-------
        // if (email != null && email.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(user.getEmail(),
        // email)) {
        // Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
        // if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
        // throw new IllegalStateException("Email taken");
        // }
        // user.setEmail(email);
        // }
        // Fix to lang and
        // long?>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // user.setZipCode(zipCode);
        user.setBio(bio);

    }
/* 
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findUserByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("user with email " + email + " not found"));
    }

    public int enableUser(String email) {
        return userRepository.enableUser(email);
    }
*/

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```html
package com.earworm.backendearworm;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM User s WHERE s.email = ?1")
    Optional<User> findUserByEmail(String email);

    // List<User> findAllByZipcode(int zipCode);

    // @Query("SELECT s FROM User s WHERE s.username = ?1")
    Optional<User> existsByUsername(String username);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE user a " + "Set a.enabled = TRUE WHERE a.email = ?1")
    int enableUser(String email);

}
```

Comment: The repository link mentioned in the question is not accessible. Can you please fix that

Comment: @RohitAgarwal It has been fixed

Comment: Thanks, I can’t see main method with @SpringBootApplication in that repo. Can you please share the reason?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal Its in here https://github.com/matfitchell/Earworm/blob/main/SourceCode/BackEnd/src/main/java/com/earworm/backendearworm/BackdendEarwormApplication.java

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the code in your repo and found out that you are excluding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class`. This is creating a problem because Spring is not able to create a database connection and without connection Repository classes bean won't be available in Spring Context.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class BackdendEarwormApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //code
    }
}
```

So please remove this exclusion and try again. Also, move `BackdendEarwormApplication` class in the `com.earworm` package so that all classes avaiable inside child packages(*backendearworm,email,registration,security and spotifyAPI*) avaialble in Spring Context.